# Factorisation of an increasing function

Tags: analysis, proof-verification

How to prove the  factorization of an increasing function to a product of an increasing function and a decreasing function in a bounded interval. 
**Sample**:
  sin(x) = (2) cos(x/2) sin(x/2)

Answer (score 0):

Let g a decreasing function and f an increasing function with $g$ $\geq f$ $\geq 0$, if $f'+g'\geq 0$ ...(1) then
$h=fg$ is an increasing function.
**Idea**:
Multiplying (1) with $g$ we get $gf'\geq  (-g')g\geq  (-g')f $ and then  $gf'+g'f\geq  0 $ and thus $h'\geq 0$.